# How to get focused child elements of windows pane control?

Tags: windows, delphi, focus, controls

I use windows UI Automation framework to access controls in other processes. I catch the system SETFOCUS messages and check the type of the focused control if it is an edit control or not. This sometimes works perfectly, but sometimes I won't get the focused control from setfocus message but only a handle to an upper control in the tree, for example a handle to a pane. What am I doing wrong?
I tried to find out which child element of the pane currently got keyboard focus by checking the UIA_HasKeyboardFocusPropertyId of the enabled child elements, but all of them will return false.
Below is the code which checks the keyboard focus property. 
Additionally, for some reason I am not able to use the Automation Element Property Identifiers. They should be listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684017(v=vs.85).aspx
I got the values from archive.org, because the content is no longer available.
In the code, "i" is the type of the currenty focused control which got the windows setfocus message.

```
if (i = 50033) then         // 50033 (pane)
begin      

   uiAuto.CreatePropertyCondition(30010, true, cond);      // 30010 (enabled property)
   if cond <> nil then
   begin
      focusedElement.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, cond, children);
      if children <> nil then
      begin
        children.Get_Length(length);
        if length > 0 then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('length: ' + IntToStr(length));

          for j := 0 to length-1 do
          begin
            children.GetElement(j, tempChildElement);
            tempChildElement.Get_CurrentControlType(k);
            Memo1.Lines.Add('child element type: ' + IntToStr(k));
            tempChildElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(30008, keybFocusBool); // 30008 (UIA_HasKeyboardFocusPropertyId)
            if keybFocusBool then
              Memo1.Lines.Add('child has keyboard focus:    TRUE');
            keybFocusbool := false;
          end;
        end;
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: *I got the values from archive.org, because the content is no longer available.* You need to use the UI Automation header files to get the values you need.

Comment: I imported UIAutomationClient_TLB, which additional header file do I need?

Comment: There are other type libraries, but I'm not sure of the details.